# Dynamically change socket.io origins

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am running node app with SocketIo and creating sockets server when starting app. In this moment also list of allowed domains is specified.

app.js

```
async function listenCallback(server) {
    try {
        const domains = await db.raw('select distinct domain from users');
        global.io = new SocketIo(server, domains);
    } catch (err) {
        server.close();
    }
}
```

socket.js

```
class SocketIo {
    constructor(server, domains) {
        domains[0].map(row => {            
            whitelist.push(`https://${row.domain}:*`)
        });
        this.io = socketIo(server, {
            origins: whitelist.join(' '),
            secure: process.env.SSL_SERVER === 'true',
        });
    }

   updateOrigins(domains) {
       ???
   }
```

How can I update origins dynamically (in updateOrigins) when server is already running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look up the origin on each connection.  Something like this will call an [origin validation function](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/47161a65d40c2587535de750ac4c7d448e5842ba/docs/API.md#serveroriginsfn) on each connection attempt (*not debugged*). Maybe it will work for you?

```
io.origins( function (origin, callback) {
  try {
    const sql = db.format ('select distinct domain from users where domain = ?', [origin])
    db.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.error ('error looking up origin in database', origin, error)
            return callback ('origin lookup failed', false)
        }
        /* if we got any rows back, we have an origin match */
        if (results.length > 0) return callback (null, true)
        return callback ('origin not allowed', false)
    })
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error ('error looking up origin in database', origin, err)
    return callback('origin lookup failed', false)
  }
});
```

You may want to implement some sort of origin cache to avoid repeating the database lookups too often.

Comment: I made it working this way and for now it's enough even though it is slower. For the future I will consider variable with maintained list of domains updated on saving a new domain into database.